# Getting Element with the id 'X' already exists on the cms pages from adminpanel in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, cms, addfield

I am using this event`adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form` to add an extra field in the cms view page.

This is the code from my observer:

```
    $model = Mage::registry('cms_page');
    $form = $observer->getForm();
    $fieldSet = $form->addFieldset(
        'url_match',
        [
            'legend' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Url store match'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
        ]
    );
    $fieldSet->addField(
        'url_match',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'url_match',
            'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Url match'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Url match'),
            'value' => $model->getUrlMatch(),
        ]
    );
```

I am getting this error message:`Element with id "url_match" already exists` ? 
The `url_match` is a custom column and was added via an upgrade. Do you know why I m getting this ? and what should I do to fix it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I had the same name from `addFieldset` with the name from `addField`. In my case I changed this:

```
$fieldSet = $form->addFieldset(
    'url_match',
    [
        'legend' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Url store match'),
        'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
    ]
);
```

into

```
    $fieldSet = $form->addFieldset(
        'url_match_field_set',
        [
            'legend' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Url store match'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide',
        ]
    );
```